# GData for iPhone can't use encoder

Tags: objective-c, encoding, nsdata, gdata

In a calendar app I'm writing, I'm trying to save the calendar data locally as well as using Googles servers, but I'm not having much luck. [GDataEntryCalendarEvent encodeWithCoder:] brings up an exception, it seems that GData doesn't do this. The code I'm using is -

```
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];

int keyNum = 1;
for (NSArray *eventsInfo in [calendarData allValues]) {
    NSString *theKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",keyNum];
    [archiver encodeObject:eventsInfo forKey:theKey];
    keyNum ++;
}

[archiver finishEncoding];

bool success = [data writeToFile:[Directories calendarDataFilePath] atomically:YES];

[archiver release];
[data release];

bool success = [calendarData writeToFile:[Directories calendarDataFilePath] atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"Calendar Data saved: %@",success);
```

and the error I'm getting is  -[GDataEntryCalendarEvent encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d60b40

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any object to be archivable using `NSKeyedArchiver`, its class needs to conform to the `NSCoding` protocol. `GDataEntryCalendarEvent` doesn't conform to it so you are getting this error. You can't use this approach to save the content.

To save an instance of `GDataEntryCalendarEvent` locally, look at [`this thread`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gdata-objectivec-client/xCBlYousmdE) which mentions a way to convert it to an XML that can be written out in a file.

Comment: Many thanks for the link - I'm finding it frustratingly difficult to find good documentation on the GData stuff, so this will be really useful.